# Is there a way to ask for a user input within the console without HTML (in ES6)?

Tags: javascript, console

Is there a way for me to make a user input where the user input is asked for in the console (without a single line of HTML), instead of 'window-prompt' or 'prompt.' Is there a syntax for it to be inside the console? For example, C has 'printf' and 'scanf' that prints directly out; is there something like that in JS, directly to the console?

Comment: do you use node.js? there is a readline() module

Comment: The console can be used to run JavaScript. But otherwise, no. You can't get input from the console

Comment: The *browser* console? No - there isn't. The browser console isn't there for users - it's for developers. And you have to open the browser to even get to it. If you want to load any JavaScript, you need to open a page. If you're using NodeJS there are options but not in the browser.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a good practice but you can do it this way:

```
<html>
  <head lang="en">
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style></style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Open console and enter in it: <strong>getValue(value) </strong></p> 
    <p>Output will be here:<span id="output"></span></p>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       const output = document.querySelector('#output'); 
       window.getValue = function (argument) {
         output.textContent = argument;
       } 
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This way you can pass many different `arguments` not only for one variable. You just need manage variables in the `getValue` function depended on `state` your program. If you need I can expand this example with `state` of program.

Also there is a good [example](https://jgthms.com/javascript-in-14-minutes/) where console is interactive:)

Answer (score 0):

As in the commentarys mentioned with pure JS there is no solution besides prompt()

But if you use node.js you can do the following

- install moudle readline

`npm i readline`

and then

```
var readline = require('readline');

var rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout
});

rl.question("What do you think of node.js? ", function(answer) {
  // TODO: Log the answer in a database
  console.log("Thank you for your valuable feedback:", answer);

  rl.close();
})
```

run it with `node <yourname>.js`

Read line has even more functionality here are some of them with examples
https://gist.github.com/DTrejo/901104